# Boot menu countdown always starts from 5 sec regardless how I configure in /etc/default/grub

Tags: rhel, boot, virtualbox, alma-linux

I am using VirtualBox and I have a Almalinux 9 VM.

When I start the VM after the VirtualBox BIOS logo disappears, I got a boot menu with 5 sec countdown. I would like to set it to 0, to speed up my boot process. For the sake of experiment I've set it to 10s via /etc/default/grub but nothing changed.  It seems that grub fully setup in this image (I am using vagrant, and the almalinux9 came from the vagrant box repo)

My /etc/default/grub file was only in place, the only thing I modified is the `5`s value to `10` in `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and added the line`GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT`

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

The screen looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You have changed some configuration data but did you update grub to apply the change? `sudo update-grub`

Comment: it seems I have no update-grub command. (searched also, not just not in the path)  I am not even sure this  boot menu comes from grub, I am totally on ground zero as one may recognize sooner or later

Comment: `update-grub` is what you use on Ubuntu based distributions. I am not familiar with Almalinux it may be different. On Arch it’s `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. I think this is the more generic command. Ubuntu have simplified theirs. Check the manual for grub-mkconfig on your system and check where your existing grub.cfg file is located. Adjust the command accordingly.

Comment: It's probably `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`. Whichever command it is, make sure the path to the grub config file is correct.

Comment: This is the relevant part of grub documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Invoking-grub_002dmkconfig

Comment: @freddy that was it, this is an answer. Many thx for all your time. (Almalinux is 100% binary compatible with RHEL, that is why I tagged the OP with rhel)

Comment: Great you solved it! You may put that into the answer box.

Comment: many thx for all. @Freddy as I wrote, if you have intent to post it as an answer, I am going to accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the credit belongs to you (and I honestly don't really care, but I will upvote your answer).

Comment: The important thing here is that there is an answer and that it is accepted. @g.pickardou can answer but not accept his own answer.

Comment: @PonJar Yes, [he can](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Freddy, apologies my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credits goes to @PonJar who enlightened the fact, that grub configuration must be updated and to @Freddy, who found out the actual command (`sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`)

So I managed to configure my boot menu countdown by editing /etc/default/grub and adding the following lines:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=<your whish goes here>
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
```

then updating the configuration:

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

This was Almalinux 9, which is RHEL 9 binary compatible.